# Tangent integration $\int \tan (2x)\tan (3x)\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

I know how to calculate $\displaystyle\int \tan (x) \tan (2x)\tan (3x)\mathrm{d}x$ with the tangent sum formula
$\tan 3x\tan 2x\tan x =\tan3x -\tan 2x -\tan x$. But I don't know how I can solve

$$\displaystyle\int \tan (2x)\tan (3x)\mathrm{d}x$$

I tried u sub, trig sub, integration by parts. But I couldn't make it.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried expanding in sin x and cos x; then in terms of sin 2x and cos 2x, and ended up with a mess with two square roots over two square roots.

Comment: Yes I have tried it, but as you said it ended up with a mess. I also tried tangent sum rule but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm really sorry to be blunt about this, but the mere idea that you can do $\displaystyle\int \tan (x) \tan (2x)\tan (3x)\,dx$, but can't do $\displaystyle\int \tan (2x)\tan (3x)\,dx$, is preposterous.

Comment: @NoNames: note that $\tan(x)\tan(2x)\tan(3x)=\tan(3x)-\tan(2x)-\tan(x)$. This follows from the equation $\tan(3x)=\frac{\tan(x)+\tan(2x)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(2x)}$, as Quanto said.

Comment: @NoNames: please do not circumvent the reputation requirement for leaving a comment by leaving a non-answer. As you can see, the claim made by the OP is not preposterous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proceed as follows

\begin{align}
\int \tan 2x\tan 3x {d}x
&=\int \frac{\sin 2x\sin 3x }{\cos 2x\cos 3x }dx\\
 &=\int \frac{(2\sin x\cos x)[\sin x(4\cos^2x-1)] }{(2\cos^2x-1)[\cos x(4\cos^2x-3) ]}dx\\
 &=2\int \frac{(1-\cos^2x)(4\cos^2x-1)}{(2\cos^2x-1)(4\cos^2x-3)}dx\\
 &=\int \left( -1 -\frac1{2\cos^2x-1} + \frac2{4\cos^2x-3}\right)dx\\
 &=-x -\int \frac{d(\tan x)}{1-\tan^2x} +2\int \frac{d(\tan x)}{1-3\tan^2x}\\
 &=-x -\tanh^{-1}(\tan x) +\frac2{\sqrt3}\tanh^{-1}(\sqrt3\tan x) 
\end{align}

Comment: I have just shocked that was amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: I think you forgot to multiply by 2 in the last integral?

Answer (score 1):

[Bicohe's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules) tell us to evaluate $\int\tan x\tan 2x\tan 3x\mathrm dx,\,\int\tan 2x\tan 3x\mathrm dx$ with the respective substitutions $c=\cos 2x,\,t=\tan x$. Since you can do one, I'll do the other:$$\begin{align}\int\tfrac{4t^2(3-t^2)}{(1-t^2)(1-3t^2)(1+t^2)}dt&=\int\left(\tfrac{4}{1-3t^2}-\tfrac{2}{1-t^2}-\tfrac{2}{1+t^2}\right)dt\\&=\tfrac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\operatorname{artanh}(t\sqrt{3})-2\operatorname{artanh}t-2\arctan t+C.\end{align}$$

Comment: I'll give a try to Bicohe's Rules, thank you !