# Trigonometric Conditional Identity and its Use in Solving Equations

Tags: trigonometry

> For $A+B+C = n\pi$,
> $\tan A + \tan B + \tan C = \tan A \tan B \tan C$

I was using this identity to solve this equation

> $\tan(x) +\tan(2x) +\tan(3x) = \tan(x)\tan(2x)\tan(3x)$

Moving forward using the converse of the above identity,

> $x + 2x + 3x = n\pi$
> $6x = n\pi$
> $x = n\pi/6$

Even though I used the identity correctly, but it isn't the solution. I checked through Desmos Graphing Calculator, and the result was

> $x = n\pi/3$ or
> $x = 2n\pi/6$

Can someone explain why only half of the solution from the identity are the actual solutions, and the former one gives extraneous solution ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please try to use MathJax to type math in the future (it's pretty much like LaTeX if you're familiar with that). Anyway, $2n\pi/6$ is equal to $n\pi/3$, did you mean something akin to $(2n+1)\pi/6$ or something?

Comment: It seems like the correct identity is [$\tan(x)\tan(2x)\tan(3x) = \tan(3x) - \tan(2x) - \tan(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016436/tangent-integration-int-tan-2x-tan-3x-mathrmdx?noredirect=1#comment8291693_4016436) (found using [Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Ctan(x)%2B%5Ctan(2x)%2B%5Ctan(3x)%3D%5Ctan(x)%5Ctan(2x)%5Ctan(3x)%24&p=1)).

Comment: "Moving forward using the converse of the identity" $\ne$ "I used the identity correctly". A statement being true does not mean its converse is true.

Comment: @BrunoB - I don't see how that identity is particularly more useful than the one given here (which is verifiable using the tangent sum-of-angles formula) in solving the problem.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I meant "correct" as in I thought that OP's identity was wrong, not that it was the right one to use for the problem itself, but I now understand the possible confusion, thank you! If both formulas were right simultaneously then we'd get $\tan(2x) + \tan(x) = 0$ by substracting the formulas which isn't true, is it?

Comment: @BrunoB - $\tan x + \tan 2x + \tan 3x = \tan x\tan 2x\tan 3x$ isn't the identity. It is the equation to be solved for $x$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ah, my bad. Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: @BrunoB - Looking at it how it is stated, I cannot blame you for thinking it was the other way around.

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks for the welcome and also for editing the question. I actually I had to type all this through my phone as my laptop had gone for repairing. I will take care of writing using MathJax in the future

Comment: @PaulSinclair I see how the converse isn't an identity. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we try your solution back in the original equation, we get
$$\tan\frac{n\pi}6 + \tan\frac{n\pi}3 + \tan\frac{n\pi}2 = \tan\frac{n\pi}6\tan\frac{n\pi}3\tan\frac{n\pi}2$$

Whereupon a problem may be noted: $\frac{n\pi}2$ is only in the domain of the tangent function when $n$ is even. Thus all odd multiples of $\frac \pi 6$ must be discarded as solutions.